# How about the limiting distribution of the minimum value?

Tags: probability, statistics

In the Fisher-Tippett theorem:
Let $X_{1},X_{2},\dots ,X_{n}$ be a sequence of independent and identically-distributed random variables with cumulative distribution function F. Suppose that there exist two sequences of real numbers $a_{n}>0$ and $b_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following limits converge to a non-degenerate distribution function:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}-b_n}{a_n}\leqslant x\right)=G(x)$$

How about the minimal case? If we take $m_n=\min\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$, how do we get the similar result?

---

We know that $m_n=-\max_n\{-X_1,\dots, -X_n\}$. But how to write this limiting distribution?

Define $M_n=\max\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$.
So it seems that
$$
\lim P(\frac{-\max\{-X_1,\dots, -X_n\}-b_n}{a_n}\le x)=G(x)?
$$
but there would be minus in the numerator.